# Unable to create an user using mysql_embedded

Tags: mysql, mariadb, users, mariadb-10.3

I am creating a docker mariadb image and wanted to create a database and user name before bootstrapping mysqld daemon. So as per the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_embedded/) I tried below queries.

```
mysql_embedded -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test ;"

mysql_embedded -e "CREATE USER admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';"

mysql_embedded -e "select user, host, password, plugin from mysql.user;"
```

The above query successfully create a database and display user information. But it didn't create the user i.e the middle query didn't get executed. Even it didn't show any error. Can't I create an user using `mysql_embedded` ?

What is the alternative to mysql_embedded. Is it mysqld --bootstrap ?

Here is a blogpost on mysql_embedded https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/using-mysql_embedded-and-mysqld-bootstrap-to-tinker-with-privilege-tables/

Comment: mysql_embedded isn't really there for creating users. embedded is when mysql is effectively a shared library for an application. I recommended creating the after bootstrap/mysql_install_db.

Comment: But from the --help option it seems we can execute any query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the docker mariadb image the best way is to set the environment variables when running the image:

- MYSQL_DATABASE
- MYSQL_USER
- MYSQL_PASSWORD

ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/

These will case the database and user to be created with grants ([ref](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L154-L168))

Comment: Sorry but I am not using official image. I am creating one from my own using Alpine. However its a general question related to Mariadb only. So let's leave about Docker.